# Opening Outlook Web App email from link causes blocked cross-origin frame access error

Tags: angularjs, outlook-web-app

I am trying to access an Outlook email from a link (i.e. https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&ItemID=xxxxxxx) from a web app I am building. Clicking on the link should open a new tab in the browser, start Outlook Web App, and open the email.

Instead, I get this error: **Blocked a frame with origin "https://outlook.office365.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame**

I am using an AngularJS ng-href directive to create the link with target=_blank to force opening in a new tab.

The email opens properly without error when it is opened within the same browser tab (without target=_blank)

I appreciate any suggested solutions to help me resolve this.

Comment: It'll be because the direct link to an email in OWA hasn't first gone through to the OWA login screen to validate you're not trying to do exactly what you're trying to do... It expects you to first go to the login page and then click an email... Not attempt to open an email and bypass the login method... No session data will have been generated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Big Chris. I get this error even after authenticating against ADFS/Office 365. I should mention that the email will open from a direct link in a blank browser tab but not from a link from my web app.

Comment: Could you write a small script that takes the email URL as a variable. You make your script open in a new tab and then (using the passed URL as variable) redirect to the URL?

Comment: PHP (myStub.php): `<?php header('Location:'.$_GET['URL']); exit(); ?>` - your application opens `myStub.php?URL=your-OWA-address` in a _blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by altering part of the query string in the URL.

From: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&ItemID=xxxxxxx

To: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#ItemID=xxxxxxx

Now the direct link will open in any frame, given you are authenticated, without any cross-origin errors.